# getting inf while calculating continuous entropy over each row of the tensor values

Tags: tensorflow, entropy, continuous

I am trying to calculate `continuous entropy` over a tensor which I received `-inf` most of the times as my numbers are too small in the tensor:

`tf.Tensor([-inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf], shape=(7,), dtype=float32)`

And this is a subsample of tensor I have:

```
tf_ent = tf.constant([  [0.096,    -0.00065,  0.99,    0.01   ],
                        [0.097,      0.033,     0.025,     0.005   ],
                        [0.009,     0.0001,    0.0009,    0.0033],
                        [0.00060,   0.001,    0.03,     0.0005 ],
                        [0.0049,   -0.08,    -0.05,    -0.00036],
                        [0.09  ,   -0.45,     0.087,    0.0023 ],
                        [0.3,      -0.23,     0.82,    -0.28   ]])
```

And this is the way I calculate continuous entropy on `each` sample of this tensor:

```
import  tensorflow as tf
import math
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def score(X):
    def entropy(data):
        if data is not None:
            data = tf.reshape(data, shape=[1, -1])
            num_samples = data.shape[0]
            if len(data.shape) == 1:
                num_dimensions = 1
            else:
                num_dimensions = data.shape[1]
            detCov = tf.linalg.det(tf.cast(tf.matmul(data, tf.transpose(data)),tf.int32)/tf.cast(num_samples,tf.int32))
            normalization = tf.math.pow(tf.cast((tf.math.multiply(2, tf.math.multiply(np.pi, tf.math.exp(1.0)))),tf.int32), num_dimensions)
            if detCov == 0:
                return -np.inf
            else:
                return 0.5 * tf.math.log(tf.math.multiply(tf.cast(normalization,tf.float32),tf.cast(detCov, tf.float32)))
    rev = tf.map_fn(entropy, X, dtype=tf.float32)
    return rev

ent_p = score(tf_ent)
```

So my question here is that, Is it ok if I multiple all the elements in the tensor by say `10000`, So I will get a score per row for the most of my rows? 
Or it might not make sense conceptually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you realise that you are seeing this behaviour because you are passing a very small number into a log function. The same thing can happen if we try to divide by a very small number. After accounting for the numerical accuracy limits of a `float32` (or whichever dtype) then we end up dividing by exactly zero.

The most common approach to avoid this issue (used in the majority or maybe even all of the 'out of the box' loss functions) is to add a very small constant value (commonly called `epsilon`) when we take a  log or divide. The principle is that the epsilon is small enough to be negligible in terms of how much it changes the loss value but that it is large enough to never have to actually divide by zero.

So maybe change to something like this:

```
def score(X):
    def entropy(data):
        epsilon = tf.constant(0.000001)
        if data is not None:
            data = tf.reshape(data, shape=[1, -1])
            num_samples = data.shape[0]
            if len(data.shape) == 1:
                num_dimensions = 1
            else:
                num_dimensions = data.shape[1]
            detCov = tf.linalg.det(tf.cast(tf.matmul(data, tf.transpose(data)),tf.int32)/tf.cast(num_samples,tf.int32))
            normalization = tf.math.pow(tf.cast((tf.math.multiply(2, tf.math.multiply(np.pi, tf.math.exp(1.0)))),tf.int32), num_dimensions)
            if detCov == 0:
                return -np.inf
            else:
                return 0.5 * tf.math.log(epsilon + tf.math.multiply(tf.cast(normalization,tf.float32),tf.cast(detCov, tf.float32)))
    rev = tf.map_fn(entropy, X, dtype=tf.float32)
    return rev

ent_p = score(tf_ent)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right as it is log, multiple will not keep the scale.

Comment: I have one more question here, I appreciate if you can share your idea with me. I am getting the same result for all of the rows in my matrix, as the elements in my matrix are all small in the same range(0.0000001, 0.7). do you have any idea what other approach I can use to get the entropy in each row but not getting the same result? do you think using `KNN` to calculate the `continuous entropy will be ok with data?